# How to clear a TextField on button press? (Swift)

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

I am trying to implement a send button for a chat app.

I have the following code:

```
TextField("Message", text: $message)
    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
Button(action: {
    self.chatModel.addMessage(message)
}) {
    Text("Send")
}
```

Is there a way to clear the textfield when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
TextField("Message", text: $message)
    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
Button(action: {
    self.chatModel.addMessage(message)
    message = ""
}) {
    Text("Send")
}
```

Comment: I don't know that it'll be much use to anybody, but I'd leave it up. If it's a problem someone will police it.